# Dot product in vectors module

Tags: python, vector

I am trying to use Python Vectors module.

```
v1 =  Vector(1,0,0)
v2 =  Vector(1,1,0)
```

the angle between these vectors is 45 Deg. I am able to get the correct value using below instruction.

```
>>> v1.angle(v2)
45.00000000000001
```

However, getting an error for v2.angle(v1).

On investigating, found that v1.dot(v2) and v2.dot(v1) give different results,
which is the reason behind this error.:

```
>>> v1.dot(v2)
1
>>> v2.dot(v1)
2
```

Unlike above, My understanding is that dot product is commutative.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Which module are you referring to?

Comment: Python has a vectors module. I installed it using command : pip install vectors.

Comment: If you are referring to https://pypi.org/project/vectors/ it is terribly out-of-date module. It is not a standard or recommended module. Please use numpy or scipy instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented pypi.org/project/vectors it is terribly out-of-date module. It is not a standard or recommended module. Please use numpy or scipy instead.

```
import numpy as np
v1  = np.array([1,0,0])
v2  = np.array([1,1,0])
```

You can find the dot product by any of these following methods:

```
print(v2.dot(v1))              # Output = 1
print(v2.dot(v1))              # Output = 1
print(np.dot(v1,v2))           # Output = 1
```

To find the angle:

```
cos = np.dot(v1,v2)/(norm(v1)*norm(v2))
angle = np.arccos(np.clip(cos, -1, 1))
```

You can also look into sympy if you prefer working symbolically. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/lines.html#sympy.geometry.line.LinearEntity.angle_between